# Flash Object won't load as soon as I enter a Rewrite directive in .htaccess

Tags: php, flash, .htaccess

my problem is that I can't get a RewriteRule to work. I have a PHP page with a flash object embedded in it. What I would like to is to write a rule in order to achieve this:

`http://mydomain.com/` should point to this:

`http://mydomain.com/AdServer.php`

and all the parameters to the flash object (in the query string, if available) should also be "copied" by the RewriteRule:

`http://mydomain.com/?sessionId="dfdsfsdfsd"#code=d83285e9352d69b3a694fa4c9543db83`

should be rewrited like this:

`http://mydomain.com/AdServer.php?sessionId="dfdsfsdfsd"#code=d83285e9352d69b3a694fa4c9543db83`

I wrote this in my .htaccess file:

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ AdServer.php`

Now, the big problem is, that the flash object does not load at all.

Can anybody please help me?

Thank you very much in advance.

David

Here's the code I use to embed the flash object in the page:

```
// Version check based upon the values defined in globals
var hasRequestedVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);

if ( hasProductInstall && !hasRequestedVersion ) {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THE FOLLOWING FOUR LINES
    // Location visited after installation is complete if installation is required
    var MMPlayerType = (isIE == true) ? "ActiveX" : "PlugIn";
    var MMredirectURL = window.location;
    document.title = document.title.slice(0, 47) + " - Flash Player Installation";
    var MMdoctitle = document.title;

    AC_FL_RunContent(
        "src", "playerProductInstall",
        "FlashVars", "MMredirectURL="+MMredirectURL+'&MMplayerType='+MMPlayerType+'&MMdoctitle='+MMdoctitle+"",
        "width", "<?=WIDTH ?>",
        "height", "<?=HEIGHT ?>",
        "align", "middle",
        "id", "AdServer",
        "quality", "high",
        "bgcolor", "#555555",
        "name", "AdServer",
        "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
        "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
        "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    );
} else if (hasRequestedVersion) {
    // if we've detected an acceptable version
    // embed the Flash Content SWF when all tests are passed
    AC_FL_RunContent(
            "src", "AdServer",
            "width", "<?=WIDTH ?>",
            "flashVars", "str=<?=$dataArray?>",
            "height", "<?=HEIGHT ?>",
            "align", "middle",
            "id", "AdServer",
            "quality", "high",
            "bgcolor", "#555555",
            "name", "AdServer",
            "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
            "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
            "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    );
  } else {  // flash is too old or we can't detect the plugin
    var alternateContent = 'Alternate HTML content should be placed here. '
    + 'This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. '
    + '<a href=http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/>Get Flash</a>';
    document.write(alternateContent);  // insert non-flash content
  }
// -->
</script>


<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
            id="AdServer" width="<?=WIDTH ?>" height="<?=HEIGHT ?>"
            codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
            <param name="movie" value="AdServer.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#555555" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#555555" />
            <param name="flashVars" value="str=<?=$dataArray?>" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />

            <embed src="AdServer.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#555555"
                width="<?=WIDTH ?>" height="<?=HEIGHT ?>" name="AdServer" align="middle"
                play="true"
                loop="false"
                flashVars="str=<?=$dataArray ?>"
                quality="high"
                allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            </embed>
    </object>
</noscript>
```

Comment: can you provide the embed code of your flash

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot `.swf` here:

```
} else if (hasRequestedVersion) {
    // if we've detected an acceptable version
    // embed the Flash Content SWF when all tests are passed
    AC_FL_RunContent(
            "src", "AdServer.swf",
```

Comment: Hi there, I added .swf. The swf sometimes, but not always loads. But now it seems, that my PHP services (that I call from Flex - the flash object-) dont work anymore.

Comment: @TouchofDestiny what does `$dataArray` return

Comment: The $dataArray is actually a base64 encoded string (sorry for the bad name).

Comment: @TouchofDestiny what is the url of PHP services